# How do I restart a failed Google Apps Script Trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a lot of time-driven triggers that query my Cloud SQL server and update information in Google Sheets.

Today, I went over my daily quota and got the following error message:

```
Jun 9, 2020, 7:37:11 AM Error   Service invoked too many times for one day: premium jdbc connection.
```

All of my triggers stopped firing at 7:40 am.  It's now 1pm.  I can manually run all of my functions, and they finish without errors.  However, I've deleted and re-created triggers, and no triggers will run on my account.  Do I need to wait 24 hours?  Is there somewhere else I can reset triggers?  Do I need to create a new Apps Script Project?

Comment: If I had that many triggers I would build them programmatically and always check that I'm not creating duplicate triggers.

Comment: Agreed. I wrote a function to delete all triggers, and then added them back programatically.  Didn't work.  Also, I was unable to create any new triggers for new functions within that project.  I manually deleted and added.  Didn't work.

I copied my bound Spreadsheet, and tried new triggers.  Didn't work.

Finally, I created a new Spreadsheet, copy/pasted all the GAS code, added new triggers.  And it works again.

So it was some kind of trigger crash/disabling at the Project level, where no Triggers in that Project could be created or run.

Comment: Once you exceed the limit your only solution is to wait a while.  Generally it won't take a whole day.  So I would review your code and insure that you are not creating duplicate triggers or perhaps creating more triggers than your quota will allow.

Comment: I'd consider making one master script that calls the others as libraries.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas): `Daily quotas are refreshed at the end of a 24-hour window; the exact time of this refresh, however, varies between users.`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, I waited until the rolling 24-hour quota refreshed (it was less than 24 hours).  The quota I was maxed out on seems to be a rolling 24-hour Usage Time, so it doesn't reset to zero, it just gives you additional Usage Time as old usage rolls off.

Helpful suggestion in comments - Create a master script to add/remove all triggers, calling the other scripts as libraries.  This allows you to quickly Delete all triggers, wait for the quota to reset/refresh, and add triggers back slowly or all at once.  Otherwise you may have Triggers that continually fire as soon as your quota has room, thereby maxing out your quota again.